# Animated gifs in iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, animated-gif

In my iOS app, I am using UIWebView's to display rich HTML content that includes animated gifs.

But what I see is empty white picture..

Is there anything specific for animated gifs?

Thanks..

Comment: is that a URL you want to load or local data?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try to load the HTML in codes, like this

```
NSString *myHTML = @"<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";
[myUIWebView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Or this

```
(void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things in this:

1. Add this class from github UIImage+animatedGIF.h. This class is used for animated gif images. By using this you can also use the animated gif images on your UIViews.
2. You have to copy all the css files related to that HTML in your bundle.
   Make sure your folder color is in blue color (rather than yellow color when it is added).